# how to get attributes of nth-child of found element

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector

I'm trying to figure out a way to get to the attributes of an nth child of an object only known to me by its index.

HTML structure is as follows:

```
<form id="myForm"> <!-- known ID -->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col innerForm">
    <div class="carousel slide"> <!-- jQuery find() result -->
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item"></div> 
      <div class="carousel-item"></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"></div> <!-- required element -->
      <div class="carousel-item"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If possible, could you please advise on a single line syntax to get to the attributes of an nth innermost object (carousel-item) without having to add to the html code.

many thanks

Comment: Why does it matter how many lines the syntax takes? Also, what research have you done, and what attempts have you made based on that research?

Comment: I'm not sure why it matters? I just laid out a problem I was faced with to the forum. I was trying to use :nth-child(n) selector, but unsuccessfully. All solutions related to this selector were all irrelevant to the issue. I like things neat so if there is a one line solution, it's usually easy to grasp at first glance, which is what I prefer. All I know is that I have to use the find() method first, but I can't find a way to refer to the nth child of found object.

Comment: Up to you. I recommend you read [ask], though, where one of the first bits of advices is to "Search, and research". Also, Stack Overflow is not a forum, it is a Q&A site, aiming to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers. As such, there are expectations of those who ask questions (and those who answer) that are generally higher than other similar venues.

Comment: Examples using the :nth-child() selector which I was able to find, refer to simple tag selection i.e: $(".myclass p:nth-child(2)").attr(...) but this won't work for the problem I've got. I have done the research, as I always do. I do appreciate your feedback, though

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If `$("#myForm .carousel .carousel-item:nth-child(" + myIndex + ")").attr(.` doesn't work for "*the problem you've got*" the it's unclear what that problem is as that solution seems to fit what you've described.

Comment: Getting the correct syntax is precisely the problem I had. Thank you! Works magic

Answer (score -1):

Hope you find this useful:

```
var carouselSlide = $("#myForm").find(".carousel.slide")

var carouselItems = carouselSlide.find(".carousel-item")

var index = 3 // taregetting fourth element

$(carouselItems[index]).css({color:"orange"})
var attrs = []
$.each( carouselItems[index].attributes, function ( index, attribute ) {
        attrs[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
} );

console.log(attrs, "attrs");
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, if there isn't a neater way, I'll definitely take from it.